# ElasticSearch - how to edit a field inside an array of a document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document in our ElasticSearch index which looks like this:

```
{
 "_index": "nm_doc",
                "_type": "nm_doc",
                "_id": "JRPXqmQBatyecf67YEfq",
                "_score": 0.86147696,
                "_source": {
                    "text": "A 29-year-old IT professional from Bhopal was convicted and sentenced to life imprisonment by an Additional Sessions Court in Pune on Wednesday for the rape and brutal murder of a woman in 2008, after she had refused his advances. Watch What Else is Making News The court found Manu Mohinder Ebrol, who worked in the same firm as the girl, of raping and killing the woman after stabbing her 18 times on the night of October 20, 2008, in her rented apartment. After committing the crime, Ebrol had fled to Bhopal. He was arrested later by Pune Police. The prosecution examined 26 witnesses for the case and forensic evidence such as call details and medical records also proved crucial. For all the latest Pune News , download Indian Express App",
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Mohinder Ebrol"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Sessions Court"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Pune Police"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Pune News"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Indian Express"
                        }
                    ]
}
```

If I wanted to edit just the first name in that array (Mohinder Ebrol) to be Manu Ebrol, how would I accomplish this via API call?  Do I need to pass in the entire array to update the one name?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out via the documentation:

The call Url is:

```
POST http://elastichost:9200/indexname/_doc/JRPXqmQBatyecf67YEfq/_update?pretty
```

And the body simply looks like this (yes, you do have to provide the entire array):

```
{
  "doc": { "entities": [
            {
                "name": "Manu Ebrol"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sessions Court"
            },
            {
                "name": "Pune Police"
            },
            {
                "name": "Pune News"
            },
            {
                "name": "Indian Express"
            }
        ] }
}
```

Hope this can help someone in the future.